# How to use a custom model's method as property in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 9 I use Blade and Spatie´s Permisisons for authorisation. In addition I redirect admins to other Controllers / Layouts / Views than I redirect normal users to.

With that approach I use the `users` table for both, admins and users. But users have a second table called `clients` with special normal user´s attributes. The `Client` model has a function to get the user attributes.

```php
public function login()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'login');
}
```

With that I am able to display the client's email address using `{{$client->login->email}}`.

But I want to use `{{$client->email}}` instead and I don't want to store the email address in `clients` **and** `users` table.

Now I created a custom method

```php
public function email()
{
    $this->login()->first()->email;
}
```

and I can use it with `{{$client->email()}}` but what do I need to do, to be able to access it with `{{$client->email}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close actually. Notice how you're using:

```php
{{ $client->login->email }}
```

That same syntax can be used inside the model, but replace `$client` with `$this`:

```php
public function email() {
  return $this->login->email;
}
```

Now, you can call:

```
{{ $client->email() }}
```

but `$client->email` (without the `()`) will not work, as this is a Method, not a property.

For that, use an Accessor:

```
public function getEmailAttribute() {
  return $this->login->email;
}
```

The code `get{Whatever}Attribute()` will convert the method `whatever()` to a property `whatever`, and *now* you can call:

```
{{ $client->email }}
```

Full documentation can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Note: This answer is for Laravel 8; syntax is wildly different in Laravel 9:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

---

Edit:

Since your model already has a `login` column, use a different name for your relationship:

```
public function loginUser() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'login');
}
```

And now call:

```
// In your view:
{{ $client->loginUser->email }}
{{ $client->loginUser()->first()->email }}
// ... etc.

// In your `Client.php` model:
$this->loginUser->email;
$this->loginUser()->first()->email;
/// ... etc.
```

Or refactor your `clients` table to use a more sensical column name, such as `user_id`, `login_id`, etc. Whatever gets you the end result you need

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you. One update: `$this->login->email` would not work as `$this->login` returns an `int $id` but `$this->login()->first()->email` is working. Did not know `get{Whatever}Attribute()` which is great and I will use this very times from now on. Chears

Comment: Right, but there's a reason for that  Using `$this->login` with your code _should_ return a `User` model instance, unless your table also has a `login` column that is overriding it (which it seems to, since you use `return $this->belongsTo(..., 'login');`) I would recommend using a different name, like `public function loginUser() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'login'); });`, then call `$client->loginUser->email`, or `$client->loginUser()->first()->email` (should be the same result, replace `$client` with `$this` as required).

Comment: Finally it acts the same, but yes, your approach would be cleaner. Thank you very much! Perfect help!!